# Giving me issues with the mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from 'react';


export default function App() {
  // State to hold the array of results
  const [joke, setJoke] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setJoke(data.results))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }, []);


  // Map over the results and create JSX elements
  const jokeElements = joke.map((item, index) => (<h2 key={index}>{item.question}</h2>));

  return (<div>{jokeElements}</div>);
}
```

It is giving me an issue of
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
How can I fix that it won't show this issue anymore?

Comment: what is in `data.results`?

Comment: Its in https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10.

Comment: Did you recompile your code after making some changes? Based on the snippet you provided, you shouldn't be having this error

Comment: This is not reproducible

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the data.result value is not an array, so you cannot map on it

You can add Elvis Operator (optional chaining) :

```
const jokeElements = joke?.map((item, index) => (<h2 key={index}>{item?.question}</h2>));
```

Or you can do this if the value of data.result can be null :

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setJoke(data.results || []))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are encountering this error is that when the component initially renders `joke` is a completely empty array that doesn’t have any item to map over. A fix to this is to check that the array isn't empty before mapping over it

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  // State to hold the array of results
  const [joke, setJoke] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setJoke(data.results))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  // Map over the results and create JSX elements
  const jokeElements =
    joke.length > 0 ? ( // check if the array has an existing item
      joke.map((item, index) => <h2 key={index}>{item.question}</h2>)
    ) : (
      <div>Empty</div>
    );

  return <div>{jokeElements}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your error has to do with the useEffect. When the joke.map line is executed, the joke state might still be an empty array, causing the "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" error.

See if doing some operational chaining helps.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [joke, setJoke] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Fetched data:", data);
        console.log("First question:", data.results[0].question);
        setJoke(data.results);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error("Fetch error:", error));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Joke state:", joke);
  }, [joke]); 


  const jokeElements = joke?.map((item, index) => (
    <h2 key={index}>{item.question}</h2>
  ));

  console.log("Rendered JSX elements:", jokeElements);

  return (
    <div>
      {jokeElements}
    </div>
  );
}
```

By adding joke?, you are stating that if there is a joke data, then execute this.

Comment: It shows up for a split of a second before it disappears off the screen. To me there shouldnt be any issues in this code and Im confused what I am doing wrong

Comment: I took your code and put it in VS Code along with the api call you are trying to make. According to the documentation, each IP can only access the API once every 5 seconds. When I console.log to see what the error was as well, I was getting a "bad request" too many attempts at using it. I threw in the the console.logs in the code above (made changes). Throw it in there and look at the console I see the questions loaded on my end and let me know!

Comment: You can always edit the answer and update it with additional information, as you did in the comments to make it even more clear

Comment: Is there a better way to do this that it doesn't give me so many issues? It is saying 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 (Too Many Requests)- but Im only requesting 10 questions.
Thank you for your help